# How can I get the touch-screen functionality on my Dell E2014T 19.5" monitor to work in Windows 10.1?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display

My question is exactly as above. I've already tried updating the driver through windows wizard and also deleting the current driver and replacing it with a fresh copy from the Dell website, beyond that, I have no clue.

Even pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Was it working before? Are the cables connected correctly according to the manual? Did You install the driver from the CD that came with the monitor?

Comment: What exactly is `Windows 10.1`?